# Is there a way to convert a blob with MIME type 'audio/wav' into a WAV file?

Tags: javascript, audio, electron, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I am building an electron app that requires recording audio and saving it in the directory of my main.js. I got the recording as a blob and then turned it into an array buffer in order to send it to my backend.

In the startRecording function I use the mediarecorder to save the audio and then send it to main

```
const startRecording = async () => {
  console.log('Recording started');
  chunks = [];
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
      chunks.push(event.data);
  };
  mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
      const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });

      // Convert Blob to buffer
      blob.arrayBuffer().then(buffer => {
          // Sending audio data to the main process using the function exposed in the preload script
          window.sendAudioToMain.send(buffer);
      }).catch(error => {
          console.error('Error converting Blob to buffer:', error);
      });

      const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const audioElement = document.getElementById('audioElement');
      audioElement.src = audioUrl;
  };
  mediaRecorder.start();
};
```

```
ipcMain.on('save-audio', async (event, buffer) => {
  try {
    // Convert the buffer back into a Blob
    const audioBlob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'audio/wav' });

    // Print the MIME type of the blob
    console.log('MIME Type:', audioBlob.type);
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
}
});
```

In my code block I have the array buffer turned back into a blob, but what I would really like to know is how I can convert this into a wav file

Answer (score 1):

The last time I checked browser implementations of `MediaRecorder` do not provide an `"audio/wav"` option.

Changing MIME type alone does not re-encode the media file.

I have written media recorded in the browser to WAV format multiple ways, mainly using and adjusting code I found in the wild for my own purposes.

Here is the most recent WAV encoder code I wrote https://github.com/guest271314/WebCodecsOpusRecorder/blob/main/WebCodecsOpusRecorder.js#L256-L341 based largely on https://github.com/higuma/wav-audio-encoder-js for real-time WAV encoding from a media when necessary for the use case.

Initialize with number of channels and sample rate

```
const wav = new WavAudioEncoder({
  numberOfChannels: this.config.decoderConfig.numberOfChannels,
  sampleRate: this.config.decoderConfig.sampleRate,
});
```

Here I'm writing an `ArrayBuffer` copied from a WebCodecs `AudioFrame` with `"f32-planar"` format that we'll have to sort out for the case of 2 channels or more later, here https://github.com/guest271314/WebCodecsOpusRecorder/blob/main/WebCodecsOpusRecorder.js#L274C1-L286C6

```
write(buffer) {
  const floats = new Float32Array(buffer);
  let channels;
  // Deinterleave
  if (this.numberOfChannels > 1) {
    channels = [
      [],
      []
    ];
    for (let i = 0, j = 0, n = 1; i < floats.length; i++) {
      channels[(n = ++n % 2)][!n ? j++ : j - 1] = floats[i];
    }
    channels = channels.map((f) => new Float32Array(f));
  } else {
    channels = [floats];
  }
  // ...
```

```
const size = frame.allocationSize({
  planeIndex: 0,
});
const chunk = new ArrayBuffer(size);
frame.copyTo(chunk, {
  planeIndex: 0,
});
wav.write(chunk);
```

When we're done

```
const data = await wav.encode();
```

which asynchrously returns a `Blob` with `"audio/wav"` MIME type, containing an encoded WAV file.

```
// https://github.com/higuma/wav-audio-encoder-js
class WavAudioEncoder {
  constructor({ sampleRate, numberOfChannels }) {
    let controller;
    let readable = new ReadableStream({
      start(c) {
        return (controller = c);
      },
    });
    Object.assign(this, {
      sampleRate,
      numberOfChannels,
      numberOfSamples: 0,
      dataViews: [],
      controller,
      readable,
    });
  }
  write(buffer) {
    const floats = new Float32Array(buffer);
    let channels;
    // Deinterleave
    if (this.numberOfChannels > 1) {
      channels = [[], []];
      for (let i = 0, j = 0, n = 1; i < floats.length; i++) {
        channels[(n = ++n % 2)][!n ? j++ : j - 1] = floats[i];
      }
      channels = channels.map((f) => new Float32Array(f));
    } else {
      channels = [floats];
    }
    const [{ length }] = channels;
    const ab = new ArrayBuffer(length * this.numberOfChannels * 2);
    const data = new DataView(ab);
    let offset = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      for (let ch = 0; ch < this.numberOfChannels; ch++) {
        let x = channels[ch][i] * 0x7fff;
        data.setInt16(
          offset,
          x < 0 ? Math.max(x, -0x8000) : Math.min(x, 0x7fff),
          true
        );
        offset += 2;
      }
    }
    this.controller.enqueue(new Uint8Array(ab));
    this.numberOfSamples += length;
  }
  setString(view, offset, str) {
    const len = str.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      view.setUint8(offset + i, str.charCodeAt(i));
    }
  }
  async encode() {
    const dataSize = this.numberOfChannels * this.numberOfSamples * 2;
    const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44);
    const view = new DataView(buffer);
    this.setString(view, 0, 'RIFF');
    view.setUint32(4, 36 + dataSize, true);
    this.setString(view, 8, 'WAVE');
    this.setString(view, 12, 'fmt ');
    view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
    view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
    view.setUint16(22, this.numberOfChannels, true);
    view.setUint32(24, this.sampleRate, true);
    view.setUint32(28, this.sampleRate * 4, true);
    view.setUint16(32, this.numberOfChannels * 2, true);
    view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
    this.setString(view, 36, 'data');
    view.setUint32(40, dataSize, true);
    this.controller.close();
    return new Blob(
      [
        buffer,
        await new Response(this.readable, {
          cache: 'no-store',
        }).arrayBuffer(),
      ],
      {
        type: 'audio/wav',
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement the wav audio encoder like this
 `
    const wav = new WavAudioEncoder({
      sampleRate: 44100, 
      numberOfChannels: 1,
    });
    wav.write(buffer);
    const data = await wav.encode();
    const mimeType = data.type;
    console.log('MIME type:', mimeType);`
But it gave me an error saying `Error: RangeError: byte length of Float32Array should be a multiple of 4` I don't think I have the implementation right, do I just pass the array to the encoder?

Comment: Where do you get `buffer` from?

Comment: In my above post I sent, I convert the blob into a buffer and send it to my backend, 
`
  mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
      const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });

      // Convert Blob to buffer
      blob.arrayBuffer().then(buffer => {

          window.sendAudioToMain.send(buffer);
`
and in the backend
`
const wav = new WavAudioEncoder({
      sampleRate: 44100, 
      numberOfChannels: 1,
    });
    wav.write(buffer);
    const data = await wav.encode();
`
Thank you very much for helping me by the way

Comment: `write()` expects an `ArrayBuffer` or `Float32Array`. In the code WebCodecs `AudioData` has `f32-planar` format. For 2 channel you have to get the channels from that single `ArrayBuffer`. For 1 channel you can pass either an `ArrayBuffer` representation of `Float32Array` data or a `Float32Array`. To get `Float32Array` from the audio in WebM container you can use `AudioContext`'s `decodeAudioData()`. Here's an example of non-real-time encoding to WAV. Open the plnkr in a separate window, see the Blob URL in console when stopped https://plnkr.co/edit/6pZQV481L4hYVhpx?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

Comment: A few questions I have, are you able to click on the url and it downloads the WAV file? I keep on getting a bad request when clicking on the Blob URL. Secondly, I would need to send the blob to my backend so I can save it as a WAV file, I have tried converting it to an array buffer, but it wouldn't save correctly as a WAV file.

Comment: Is your stream 1 channel or 2 channel? The 1 channel example at the linked plnkr works.

Comment: The audio buffer looks like this
AudioBuffer
duration
: 
1.98
length
: 
95040
numberOfChannels
: 
2
sampleRate
: 
48000
It's fine if the url does not work though. Knowing how to send it and convert it in my back end is what my end goal is.

Comment: Here's an example of the same code that expects a Web Audio API `AudioBuffer` to be passed to `write()`. See `console` for the WAV Blob URL to play. Tested on Chromium 124 and Firefox 125 https://run.plnkr.co/preview/clttglzv700042v7779n173m3/

Comment: Thank you, https://run.plnkr.co/abd78b19-b100-48d5-a2af-7b347583dd59 this is the link to the audio blob and it still doesn't play. Does the number of channels differ from computer to computer? I would like to have this be able to run on most machines.

Comment: If you save that Blob URL printed in the console at https://run.plnkr.co/preview/clttglzv700042v7779n173m3/ it plays. The number of channels shouldn't matter. Pass a Web Audio API `AudioBuffer` to `WavAudioEncoder` `write()` method, call the asynchronous `encode()` method to return a `Promise` that fulfills with a `Blob` with `type` set to `"audio/wav"` and is actually an encoded WAV file.

Comment: I went back to inspect this link to examine the WAV implementation and I keep on getting an error run.plnkr.co/preview/clttglzv700042v7779n173m3, could you send it again so I could analyze it?

Comment: When I click the blob link, this is what I see https://i.imgur.com/4kteosp.png

Comment: I put it all in a repository, if you could check it out. I talked to someone else about the issue and they said I should be putting it in mp3 format https://github.com/zoistie/AudioElectron . I just want the blob to be able to be saved so that vscode media player can recognize it and play it back.

Comment: WAV or MP3? What media containers and codecs does vscode media player support?

Comment: @originofpork Here you go https://github.com/guest271314/AudioElectron/tree/guest271314-patch-1, plnkr to demonstrate https://run.plnkr.co/preview/cltxsk1mo000a2v77bc0mbk2n/. I adjusted WavAudioEncoder.write() to handle ArrayBuffer that is f32-planar from WebCodecs AudioData or Web Audio API AudioBuffer. The WAV file is set as src of the audio element.

Comment: @originofpork For MP3 see https://github.com/guest271314/MP3Recorder and plnkr  https://plnkr.co/edit/k8MgcmI1rfxjH1pG?preview.

Comment: Holy cow thank you so much for the pr this works very nicely.

Comment: @originofpork No worries. Writing the PR provided me an opportunity to update `write()` to handle `AudioBuffer` from Web Audio API or `ArrayBuffer` from WebCodecs `AudioData`.